# Deadlocks in Oracle

Tags: oracle, database-deadlocks

I want to  make a script where the oracle sessions which go into a deadlock are killed automatically.Is it possible to find out the session id  for the sessions which go into a deadlock.As of now I have to bounce the database to remove the deadlock.Is any solution to this problem possible?

Comment: Oracle [detects deadlocks automatically](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/consist.htm#CNCPT1336), and issues an ORA-00060 to one of the sessions. What exactly are you seeing and how are you generating the scenario?

Answer (score 7):

> I want to make a script where the oracle sessions which go into a deadlock are killed automatically

**EDIT** Explained in a better way, corrected few sentences, and added a test case to demonstrate deadlock scenario.

Why do you want to re-invent the wheel? **Oracle detects a deadlock automatically, throws `ORA-00060: deadlock detected while waiting for resource`, and rolls back one of the transactions involved in the deadlock which Oracle decided as the victim. The previous successful transactions are not rolled back. Even after the deadlock error, if a commit is issued, the previous successful transaction will be committed. At this time, the other session's transaction will also succeed and you could issue a commit.** There is nothing that you need to explicitly do here. Deadlocks are automatically cleared -- you never need to **clear** them.

Usually, Oracle takes a second or two to detect a deadlock and throws the error.

You can try with a simple test case as demonstrated here : [Understanding Oracle Deadlock](https://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2014/02/25/oracle-deadlock-replication/)

Let's look at a test case -

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE t_test(col_1 NUMBER, col_2 NUMBER);

Table created
SQL> INSERT INTO t_test VALUES(1,2);

1 row inserted
SQL> INSERT INTO t_test VALUES(3,4);

1 row inserted

SQL> COMMIT;

Commit complete

SQL> SELECT * FROM t_test;

     COL_1      COL_2
---------- ----------
         1          2
         3          4
```

Note the time of each transaction, I have set time on timing on for a better understanding.

**SESSION : 1**

```
12:16:06 SQL> UPDATE t_test SET col_1 = 5 WHERE col_2=2;

1 row updated.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.00
```

**SESSION : 2**

```
12:16:04 SQL> UPDATE t_test SET col_1 = 6 WHERE col_2=4;

1 row updated.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.00
12:16:31 SQL> UPDATE t_test SET col_1 = 7 WHERE col_2=2;
```

At this point, **SESSION 2 keeps waiting**.

**SESSION : 1**

```
12:16:15 SQL> UPDATE t_test SET col_1 = 8 WHERE col_2=4;
```

At this point, **SESSION 2** is the victim of deadlock, **SESSION 1** is still waiting.

Let's look at the session details from **SESSION 2** -

```
12:22:15 SQL> select sid,status,program,sql_id, state, wait_class, blocking_session_status, event from v$session where schemaname='LALIT' and program='sqlplus.exe';

       SID STATUS   PROGRAM         SQL_ID        STATE               WAIT_CLASS      BLOCKING_SE EVENT
---------- -------- --------------- ------------- ------------------- --------------- ----------- ----------------------------------------------------------------
        14 ACTIVE   sqlplus.exe     60qmqpmbmyhxn WAITED SHORT TIME   Network         NOT IN WAIT SQL*Net message to client
       134 ACTIVE   sqlplus.exe     5x0zg4qwus29v WAITING             Application     VALID       enq: TX - row lock contention

Elapsed: 00:00:00.00
12:22:18 SQL>
```

So, `v$session` details when viewed in **SESSION 2**, i.e. SID 14, says the status is **ACTIVE**.

Let's look at the session details from another session, lets call it **SESSION 3** for the sake. Remember, **SESSION 1** is still waiting.

```
SQL> set time on timing on
12:24:41 SQL> select sid,status,program,sql_id, state, wait_class, blocking_session_status, event from v$session where schemaname='LALIT' and program='sqlplus.exe'

       SID STATUS   PROGRAM         SQL_ID        STATE               WAIT_CLASS BLOCKING_SE EVENT
---------- -------- --------------- ------------- ------------------- ---------- ----------- ------------------------------
        13 ACTIVE   sqlplus.exe     60qmqpmbmyhxn WAITED SHORT TIME   Network    NOT IN WAIT SQL*Net message to client
        14 INACTIVE sqlplus.exe                   WAITING             Idle       NO HOLDER   SQL*Net message from client
       134 ACTIVE   sqlplus.exe     5x0zg4qwus29v WAITING             Applicatio VALID       enq: TX - row lock contention
                                                                      n


Elapsed: 00:00:00.01
12:24:44 SQL>
```

So, for other sessions, **SESSION 2**, i.e. SID 14, is **INACTIVE**. **SESSION 1** is still **WAITING** with event `enq: TX - row lock contention`.

Let's commit **SESSION 2** -

```
12:22:18 SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.01
12:25:43 SQL>
```

At this point, the lock is released for **SESSION 1**, let's commit session 1 as well -

```
12:16:15 SQL> UPDATE t_test SET col_1 = 8 WHERE col_2=4;

1 row updated.

Elapsed: 00:08:27.29
12:25:43 SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.00
12:26:26 SQL>
```

`Elapsed: 00:08:27.29` shows **SESSION 1** was waiting that long till **SESSION 2** was committed.

To summarize, **here is the entire story of session 1** -

```
12:16:06 SQL> UPDATE t_test SET col_1 = 5 WHERE col_2=2;

1 row updated.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.00
12:16:15 SQL> UPDATE t_test SET col_1 = 8 WHERE col_2=4;

1 row updated.

Elapsed: 00:08:27.29
12:25:43 SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.00
12:26:26 SQL>
```

To summarize, **here is the entire story of session 2** -

```
12:16:04 SQL> UPDATE t_test SET col_1 = 6 WHERE col_2=4;

1 row updated.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.00
12:16:31 SQL> UPDATE t_test SET col_1 = 7 WHERE col_2=2;
UPDATE t_test SET col_1 = 7 WHERE col_2=2
                                  *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00060: deadlock detected while waiting for resource


Elapsed: 00:00:24.47
12:22:15 SQL> select sid,status,program,sql_id, state, wait_class, blocking_session_status, event from v$session where schemaname='LALIT' and program='sqlplus.exe';

       SID STATUS   PROGRAM         SQL_ID        STATE               WAIT_CLASS      BLOCKING_SE EVENT
---------- -------- --------------- ------------- ------------------- --------------- ----------- ----------------------------------------------------------------
        14 ACTIVE   sqlplus.exe     60qmqpmbmyhxn WAITED SHORT TIME   Network         NOT IN WAIT SQL*Net message to client
       134 ACTIVE   sqlplus.exe     5x0zg4qwus29v WAITING             Application     VALID       enq: TX - row lock contention

Elapsed: 00:00:00.00
12:22:18 SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.01
12:25:43 SQL>
```

Now, let's see **which transaction actually got rolled back and which got committed** -

```
12:25:43 SQL> select * from t_test;

     COL_1      COL_2
---------- ----------
         5          2
         8          4

Elapsed: 00:00:00.00
12:30:36 SQL>
```

**Conclusion**

In my opinion, the best way to know the session details of a deadlock is to log the details as verbose as possible. Else, it is a nightmare for a DBA to investigate without proper information logged. For that matter, even a Developer would find it to be an herculean task to rectify and fix the actual design flaw if the deadlock error details are not logged verbosely. And to conclude with a one liner statement, A deadlock is due to design flaw, **Oracle is just the victim and the application being the culprit. Deadlocks are scary, but they point out the design flaws that must be rectified sooner or later.**

Comment: Spot on. There is a difference between a deadlock and a blocking session and Oracle will clear deadlocks (usually) within about 3 seconds or so.

Comment: :-) I have had seen the deadlocks so many times while wotking with many legacy applications. End of the day, we could only reverse engineer the error logs and tried to re-run the killed session. We could NEVER detect a deadlock before Oracle, it is internally detected and handled much faster. If I had to do anything substantial, then I would first rectify the application design. Deadlocks are scary, but they point out the design flaws.

Comment: Correct. An ounce of prevention is worth a pound of cure in this case.

Comment: Oracle does not kill a session when it detects a deadlock.  It rolls back one of the two deadlocked statements (whichever is chosen as the victim) but both sessions are still there.

Comment: @Justin, Thanks for the comment. I should have said thread instead of session. A session may spawn multiple threads. Personally, I have never had the need to kill a session when a process failed due to deadlock. Oracle cleared it automatically, always. A quote by T.Kyte *Deadlocks are automatically cleared -- you never need to "clear" them. One or the other session will have their statement cancelled. They will become unblocked. *

Comment: @LalitKumarB - I don't think "thread" is right.  A session is single-threaded, you can't have a session with multiple threads (a session can spawn other sessions using parallel query or `dbms_job` or `dbms_scheduler` but I don't think that's what you're thinking about).  When a deadlock is detected, one statement is rolled back and an error is thrown.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,But I had some misconception which I am able to figure out from your answer .The situation which I am facing is not of a deadlock but where some users update some table and dont perform commit operation and after which that table becomes inaccessible which causes my application to come to halt.Can anything be done to know and kill the session which is holding a lock on a table for a long time?

Answer (score 0):

user 1

```
update table_c set id = 200 where id = 13;
BEGIN
DBMS_LOCK.sleep(14);
END;
/
update table_c set id = 200 where id = 15;
```

user 2

```
update table_c set id = 2000 where id = 15;

BEGIN
DBMS_LOCK.sleep(14);
END;
/

update table_c set id = 1000 where id = 13;
```

Answer (score 0):

**What is a Deadlock?**

A deadlock occurs when a session (A) wants a resource held by another session (B) , but that session also wants a resource held by the first session (A). There can be more than 2 sessions involved but the idea is the same.

**Diagnostic information produced by an ORA-60**

ORA-60 error normally writes the **error message in the alert**.log together with the name of the trace file created. The exact format of this varies between Oracle releases. The trace
file will be written to the directory indicated by the **USER_DUMP_DEST or BACKGROUND_DUMP_DEST**, depending on the type of process that creates the trace file.

**Resolving Deadlock**

Oracle is smart and it is able to find deadlock situation within 3 seconds. Below are the options to avoid deadlocks inside the database

Ask the session getting deadlock **error ORA-00060** to issue either COMMIT or ROLLBACK

Ask the waiting session to kill the SQL / transaction

Look inside alert log / trace file for the sessions involved in deadlock and inform application team to improve the code

As a DBA, whenever you get a Deadlock alert, immediately contact application team and inform them.