# Can oracle Deadlocks not be rolled back?

Tags: oracle, database-deadlocks

Is it possible that a Deadlock in Oracle won't be rolled back in which we have to manually clear the Deadlock?

I read in the Oracle Documentation, it says:

> Oracle Database automatically detects deadlocks and resolves them by
>   rolling back one statement involved in the deadlock, releasing one set
>   of the conflicting row locks.

My question is, can there be a scenario where this does not happen?

Comment: See if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/a/28455397/3989608 and this http://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2014/02/25/understanding-oracle-deadlock/

Comment: @LalitKumarB thank you. it was a nice article and now i have a better understanding about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible that a Deadlock is not being rolled back in which we have to manually clear the Deadlock.

Well, it is not that *all* the transactions are rolled back. Oracle detects a deadlock automatically, throws `ORA-00060: deadlock detected while waiting for resource`, and rolls back one of the transactions involved in the deadlock which Oracle decided as the victim. The previous successful transactions are not rolled back. Even after the deadlock error, if a commit is issued, the previous successful transaction will be committed. At this time, the other session's transaction will also succeed and you could issue a commit.

Deadlocks are automatically cleared -- you never need to clear them.

For a detailed example, look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28455397/3989608). You can reproduce with a simple test case as demonstrated here : [Understanding Oracle Deadlock](http://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2014/02/25/understanding-oracle-deadlock/)

Comment: Oracle will NOT rollback the whole transaction. It will ONLY rollback the very last SQL statement of the transaction. The transaction is still left open.

Comment: Yes. As I said, the previous successful transactions are not rolled back.

Comment: But previous successful transaction is not the same as previous successful statement.